# How to remove white space character when inserting data through prepared statement in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I am using SQL Server as the database and I want to insert data to a table through my Java application. It is successful but when I retrieve the data which has been just inserted I find there is some whitespace character behind the word.
I debugged my program but everything looks fine, even until preparedStatement.executeUpdate(); there is no whitespace character.
I am really confused where my mistake is.

```
public static void updateDatabase(Connection conn) throws SQLException{
        for(ArrayList<String> bookData : bookDataList){
            if("newId".equalsIgnoreCase((String) bookData.get(0))){
                PreparedStatement insertPS = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Book (Title, Author, Quantity) VALUES (?,?,?)");
                insertPS.setString(1, bookData.get(1));
                insertPS.setString(2, bookData.get(2));
                insertPS.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(bookData.get(3)));
                insertPS.executeUpdate();
                insertPS.close();
            }else{
                PreparedStatement updatePS = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE Book SET Quantity = ? WHERE BookId = ?");
                updatePS.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(bookData.get(3)));
                updatePS.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(bookData.get(0)));
                updatePS.executeUpdate();
                updatePS.close();
            }
        }
        conn.close();
    }
```

Comment: The code has just been inserted

Comment: Which data field(s) is/are getting white space? Title, Author?...did you try bookData.get().trim() for those?

Comment: both of them. I didn't trim it but when I debugged it, the size is exactly the same.

Comment: I have just tried it and yes, there are still the whitespaces. i debugged the value on bookData.get(1).trim() and there is no whitespaces. but when I checked on the database, there are whitespaces :(

Comment: One potential cause of space padding is that your `Title` and `Author` columns are defined as `CHAR(99)`, not `VARCHAR(99)`, which will then pad any inserted value with spaces to length 99.

Comment: I double checked and the type is VARCHAR(50). and still getting these whitespaces

Comment: Are you sure the character at the end of your DB field is a whitespace AKA `CHAR(32)` and not some other funky thing that is just being displayed as a whitespace?  Reading straight from your SQL Server DB, run this: `SELECT ASCII(RIGHT([YourField], 1) FROM [YourTable]`

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? Also via JDBC?

Comment: @LDMJoe I run that query and the result is 32.

Comment: @SkinnyJ yes exactly. through JDBC also. So I retrieve the data, process it, and do insert/update database.

Comment: @twindicated70 I mean **after** you insert/update, when you retrieve the data and see the whitespace, is that a jdbc retrieval?

Comment: @SkinnyJ yes, I can see it in my application :(

Comment: @SkinnyJ yes it is jdbc retrieval. I can see it in my application and in the database also after insert. So I am thinking the problem is probably I did something wrong when I insert data to the database.